# associated points of locally Noetherian scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme with finite number of associated points. Let $f$ be a function on $X$, that is $f$ is a global section of the structure sheaf, 
 if $f$ vanishes at one associated point, is $f$ a zerodivisor?

If $X$ is an affine Noetherian scheme, $f$ is a zerodivisor. Is it right when $X$ is not affine?

Comment: It's a good question and I thought of it some months ago, but I didn't reach the solution. However, I'd like to recall that the sheaf $f \mathcal{O}_X$ is invertible iff $f$ does not vanish at any associated point. Maybe it could be useful.

Comment: It seems this is not the case if $X$ has only one associated point.